# Problem when importing another class from a shared library resulting "Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve"

Tags: angular, import, dto, nrwl-nx

I am facing an extremely weird behavior with my Angular project.
Context:

1. I have an NX workspace with angular and nestJS
2. They have their own libs but there is also a shared lib for DTOs. Purpose: I defined DTOs once and both front and back end can share these.

Let's say that I have **ComponentA** and **ComponentB**. ComponentA also has a service **ServiceA**.

There is a DTO file in the DTO library for countries: **country.dto.ts**.
This file has DTOs for get/create: **CountryGetDto** and **CountryCreateDto**.
They typically look like this:

```
import { IsDateString, IsNotEmpty, IsNumber, IsOptional, IsString } from "class-validator";
import { Country, Continent, City } from "@prisma/client"
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class CountryCreateDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    @IsNumber()
    @IsOptional()
    id?: number;
    ...
}

export class CountryGetDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    @IsNumber()
    @IsOptional()
    id?: number;
    ...
}
```

The awkward situation is that I am getting bunch of compilation errors such as:

> ./node_modules/*/index.js:18:14-37 - Error: Module not found: Error:
> Can't resolve '*' in '/home/user/git/app/node_modules/*' BREAKING
> CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules
> by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module
> and configure a polyfill for it.
>
> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
> - install 'util' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "util": false }

***ONLY when I import the CountryCreateDto into ComponentA or its children.***

I can import **CountryGetDto** into **ComponentA** with no problem!

I can import **CountryCreateDto** into **ComponentB** with no problem!

I can import **CountryCreateDto** into **ServiceA** with no problem!

Now the best part is that I am importing in the NX workspace with @ scopes:

```
import { CountryGetDto } from '@myapp/dtos'; // works
import { CountryCreateDto } from '@myapp/dtos'; // DOES NOT work
import { CountryCreateDto } from '../../../../../../shared/dtos/src/lib/country/country.dto'; // works
```

Sadly, I can not reproduce this error in a minimal format. I also don't know if it is the NX or Angular is the problem. I can't interpret the compilation errors, they don't make any sense in this context.

Edit:
For instance one of the errors is this:

> ./node_modules/@nestjs/common/file-stream/streamable-file.js:7:17-34 -
> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in
> '/home/user/git/myapp/node_modules/@nestjs/common/file-stream'
> And here is the relevant line in that file:
> const stream_1 = require("stream");

New edit: it is definitely `@nestjs/swagger`, which after being removed solves the compilation issues.

(Note: I read that importing swagger (in this case indirectly via DTOs) can cause this issue. I tried to remove swagger from CountryDto, which did not help. I am importing similarly other DTOs with not issue.)